# Checking equality of variables in array

Tags: php

I want a PHP program to tell if an array contains any equal data. For that I'm writing this code but it always returns false, even though I have given equal values at position array position 1 and 2. Can anyone help me find out what is wrong with this code?

```
$a[0]=qwe;
$a[1]=abc;
$a[2]=abc;
$a[3]=xyz;

if(is_equal($a))
{
   echo "True";
}
else
{
   echo "False";
}

function is_equal($a)
{
    $size=sizeof($a);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $size-2; $i++)
    {
        if ($a[i] === $a[i+1])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: The number of items in the array is `count($a)`, not `sizeof($a)`, I think. Are you not missing some quotes in the first four lines?

Comment: @CompuChip Have you read the manual? `sizeof` is an alias of `count` ;)

Comment: Apparently not :) Thanks @kingkero!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to write a function for that, you can use [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique):

```
if ($array !== array_unique($array))
{
  // There were duplicate values
}
```

Comment: True but what if the goal is to identify unique or non-unique values ?  Or, as the code might indicate, to identify consecutive identical values, ignoring them if they're not consecutive... From where I see it `array_unique()` is to PHP what distinct is to SQL

Comment: @Bartdude There are other built-in array functions to get for example the difference if the OP should need that. From how I read the question, this is all the OP needs, but it could always be adapted according to the exact specifications.

Comment: can u plz elaborate it, actually i m new to php

Comment: @user3036851 There is not much more to it, if you want you can replace the contents of your whole function with `return ($a !== array_unique($a));` and that is about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your existing code is that

```
if ($a[i] === $a[i+1])
```

should be

```
if ($a[$i] === $a[$i+1])
```

PHP variables start with a `$`, otherwise `i` is treated as a constant, and as the constant isn't defined, then a string value of "i"

`$a["i"]` doesn't exist, therefore it can never be equal to anything; and `$a[i+1]` will add 1 to `i` giving 1, so it is always a comparison of a non-existent array element against element 1